# Linq query from collection inside other collection

Tags: c#, linq

I have two objects: `Poll` and `PollIp` (one-to-many).
I want to select all polls that not have concrete Ip address. How can I do this?
My code:

```
public Poll GetNextPoll(string ipAddress)
{
  return Database.Polls
    .Where(p => p.IsPublish.Value && p.PollIps.Any(i => i.IpAdress != ipAddress))
    .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Thanks

**EDIT**
In the DB I have following:

Poll:

```
id    Name     ...   

1     Poll1  
2     Poll2
```

PollIp

```
PollId      IpAdress   
1           ::1 (it's my IP)
```

And, query must return `Poll` with id equal 2, because in the `PollIp` no `PollId` with 2

Comment: Well, you've given some code... how does that not do what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public IEnumerable<Poll> GetPolls(string ipAddress)
{
    return Database.Polls.Where(p => p.PollIps.All(i => i.IpAdress != ipAddress))
}
```